# How to prove that open ordinal space (i.e. $[0,\Omega)$) with order topology is countably compact and pseudocompact but not compact?

Tags: general-topology, compactness

> How to prove that open ordinal space (i.e. $[0,\Omega)$) with order topology is countably compact but not compact, Where $\Omega$ is the first uncountable ordinal?

We know that every compact space is countably compact, but not the converse. Open ordinal space is an example of a countably compact space which is not compact. But I don't know  how I can show that it is countably compact but not compact?

Comment: What have you tried? Hint: what is the cofinality of $\Omega$?

Comment: I dont know what is the cofinality of $\Omega$

Comment: Maybe you might want to look it up?

Comment: Note that all elements of $[0,\Omega)$ are countable ordinals. If you take a countable union of countable ordinals, you get a countable ordinal. Therefore, the cofinality of $[0,\Omega)$ must be $\Omega$. So, to show that it is not compact, you can take $[0,\Omega)=\bigcup_{x\in\Omega}[0,x)$

Comment: But how can i show that [0,$\Omega$) is countably compact. ?

Comment: It's enough to show that every countable subset has a limit point. This follows from the cofinality fact.

Comment: If you have proof ....please share with me .